# Scanning a Barcode with a Hybrid Android Smartphone with Appium

Tags: android, testing, appium, appium-android

is it possible on Appium to scan a Barcode?

First of all, my app scans Barcodes with a barcode Scanner running on Android.

I know the method to start appium with --relaxed securitys and then using the adb shell. After that you can use a cmd command to do it, but it wont work for me cause i am not allowed to start appium with relaxed securitys. Dont ask why^^

So i have to do it in a different way. Would it be possible to have the barcode to be storaged on the smartphone as a png and when my app whants to scan something to inject that png file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaking, but I don't see this as possible to do it like that. I don't think You can inject png file into any kind of reader, to read it from itself.

Comment: Hey thank you and sry for the late reply, holidays^^ 
Could there be a different way to scan a barcode with Appium? Or is the only way the cmd Command?

Comment: If barcode reader is "must-have" feature to automate, I would suggest to investigate about eventual api for barcode reader (maybe). This is quite tricky, I see your problem.

Comment: Its the main-feature. I will talk to the Security guys, seems like there is no other way. But thanks for the help

Comment: how could u perform using adb shell? i'm facing the same issue